# Ignore some values at return

Tags: syntax, symbols, variable

Is there *Mathematica* analogue of Python `_` (underscore) or Matlab `~`, a special variable, that can be used when a function returns a list and only some of the list elements are needed while others just ignored. E.g.:

```
f[x_] = {x^ 2, x^ 3};
{a1, _} = f[2]
```

Comment: In this particular case, you could use `a1 = f[2][[1]]`.

Comment: Have a look at `Part` or `Extract`. Part would be shorter code. Both can select multiple items from the returned list.

Comment: Is this ok: `a /: Set[a, _] := Null`? No value can be set to a, but can be `SetDelayed` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of an underscore, a "throwaway" symbol can be used.  For instance,

```
f[x_] = {x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5};
{a1, z, z, a2} = f[2]
```

`a1` and `a2` have their desired values, and the others are overwritten into `z` at the cost of only a single symbol.

Comment: That seems to be the easiest way. I figured out the dollar sign is a legal variable name and probably might as well be used for trash-variable.

Comment: Yes, `$z` would work just fine.  Welcome to Mathematica.StackExchange.

Comment: @Kuba,  Using a [Formal Symbol](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html) is a clever idea (+1), although `Off[Set::wrsym]` would be necessary to avoid what could be many error messages.

Comment: or `f[x_] = {x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5};
Module[{z},
 {a1, z, z, a2} = f[2]]`

Comment: @bbgodfrey I had messages window hiden so I haven't noticed it :P but anyway, what was I expecting? :P

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to write

```
a1 = f[2][[1]]
```

> 4

```
Clear[a1]

{a1, _} = f[2];
```

also assigns `4` to `a1` but produces an error message which you can turn off temporarily with `Quiet`:

```
Quiet[{a1, _} = f[2]];

a1
```

> 4